# How to properly unwrap this shape

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm looking to unwrap this shape. All I know is I need to unwrap and the fact that the shape is different shapes glued together looks like it will give me problems when I'm trying to unwrap it. Can I get help with this? I have no idea what to do.[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM&ab_channel=Blender

Comment: the blend file please?

Comment: how does your texture look like?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a blend file...I'm new here

Comment: Also, the texture will just be smooth colors. All one color except him in his underwear.